# Restful webservices

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, netbeans-7

I am new to JAVA and I am trying to develop restful web service using netbeans IDE ,i have MYSQL database.I have referred to the netbeans tutorial to develop this service.I have have added a method to the entity class which returns the rows based on company name passed.I tried the option test restful services,It gave me list of services on left side ,but when i try to test the service (method that i have added manually in entity class) it gives me a HTTP 404 error:request resource not found.I don't understand where the problem lies.I am using Glassfish server.
Can anybody help me in this regard.Thanks in advace.
The following is my code:

**1.AbstractFacade.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }
}
```

**2.MyTableFacadeREST.java**

```
@Stateless
@Path("com.entities.mytable")
public class MyTableFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<MyTable> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WSDataBasePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public MyTableFacadeREST() {
        super(MyTable.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public void create(MyTable entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

    @PUT
    @Override
    @Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public void edit(MyTable entity) {
        super.edit(entity);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public MyTable find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Override
    @Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public List<MyTable> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{from}/{to}")
    @Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public List<MyTable> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
        return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String countREST() {
        return String.valueOf(super.count());
    }

//added method to fetch rows corresponding to company passed
   @GET
    @Path("companyname/{companyname}")
    @Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
    public List<MyTable> findByCompanyname(@PathParam("companyname") String name){
       return (List<MyTable>)(MyTable)em.createNamedQuery("MyTable.findByCompanyname").setParameter("companyname",name).getResultList();
    }
    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

}
```

**3.MyTable.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTable")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "MyTable.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM MyTable m"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MyTable.findByCompanyid", query = "SELECT m FROM MyTable m WHERE m.companyid = :companyid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MyTable.findByCompanyname", query = "SELECT m FROM MyTable m WHERE m.companyname = :companyname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MyTable.findByCompanyasset", query = "SELECT m FROM MyTable m WHERE m.companyasset = :companyasset"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MyTable.findByAssetname", query = "SELECT m FROM MyTable m WHERE m.assetname = :assetname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "MyTable.findByAssetdescription", query = "SELECT m FROM MyTable m WHERE m.assetdescription = :assetdescription")})
public class MyTable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Company_id")
    private Integer companyid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Company_name")
    private String companyname;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Company_asset")
    private String companyasset;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Asset_name")
    private String assetname;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "Asset_description")
    private String assetdescription;

    public MyTable() {
    }

    public MyTable(Integer companyid) {
        this.companyid = companyid;
    }

    public MyTable(Integer companyid, String companyname) {
        this.companyid = companyid;
        this.companyname = companyname;
    }

    public Integer getCompanyid() {
        return companyid;
    }

    public void setCompanyid(Integer companyid) {
        this.companyid = companyid;
    }

    public String getCompanyname() {
        return companyname;
    }

    public void setCompanyname(String companyname) {
        this.companyname = companyname;
    }

    public String getCompanyasset() {
        return companyasset;
    }

    public void setCompanyasset(String companyasset) {
        this.companyasset = companyasset;
    }

    public String getAssetname() {
        return assetname;
    }

    public void setAssetname(String assetname) {
        this.assetname = assetname;
    }

    public String getAssetdescription() {
        return assetdescription;
    }

    public void setAssetdescription(String assetdescription) {
        this.assetdescription = assetdescription;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (companyid != null ? companyid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof MyTable)) {
            return false;
        }
        MyTable other = (MyTable) object;
        if ((this.companyid == null && other.companyid != null) || (this.companyid != null && !this.companyid.equals(other.companyid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.entities.MyTable[ companyid=" + companyid + " ]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, see what your base url is. To do this, you can try clicking run in netbeans (double click in project). Then add to the base url "/com.entities.mytable" as indicated by the annotation Path in your resource.

Comment: Hi Jams,I tried using URL is "http://localhost:8080/WSDataBase/webresources/com.entities.mytable" ,I get list of services on left side including the one which i added manually.But on clicking that service i get a http 404 error.Do i need to make any changes in web.xml? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be thay you have not defined the base url for your service. You need to tell JAX-RS (Jersey is the implementation in GlassFish) which url pattern it must intercept as your endpoint (base url).

One way of achieving this is using an Application Class which can be added to any package in the project (you could alternatively define the necessary in a web.xml). [See this answer for a simple Application Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508159/jax-rs-glassfish-eclipse-a-simple-web-service-doesnt-work/23575215#23575215).